# INSERT query syntax error in ASP.NET C# with Access

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I am trying to insert data into an Access database with C#. The error I receive is

> Insert Into Statement syntax error

The code is

```
textBox5.Text = ins; //string value
string into = "INSERT INTO customersales(c-invoiceNo,c-invoiceDate, c-discount, c-rant,c-paid, c-due) values ('" +textBox5.Text.ToString() + "'," + dateTimePicker1.Text + "," + diccombo.Text.Trim() + "," + GRANTTXT.Text + "," + TXTPAID.Text + ","+ txtdue.Text + ")";
 con.Open();
 cmd = new OleDbCommand(into, con);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 con.Close();
```

**Table name :** customersales

**columnname :**

```
id (autonumber)
c-invoiceNo (text)
c-invoiceDate  (date/time)
c-discount (currency)
c-grant (currency)
c-paid (currency)
c-due (currency)
```

Comment: Copy and paste the value of `into` into a query window in MS Access.  Does it work?

Comment: Into is not a reserved word in C sharp?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a parameterized query, like this

```csharp
string into = 
        "INSERT INTO [customersales] ([c-invoiceNo], [c-invoiceDate], [c-discount], [c-grant], [c-paid], [c-due]) " +
        "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
con.Open();
cmd = new OleDbCommand(into, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", textBox5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", diccombo.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", GRANTTXT.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TXTPAID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtdue.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: this code is not working properly and same error occurred. please suggest again.

Comment: @user2834203 I have updated my answer. (Changed `dateTimePicker1.Value` to `dateTimePicker1.Value.Date`.)

Answer (score 0):

Change your query in this way,

```
  string into = "INSERT INTO customersales(c-invoiceNo,c-invoiceDate, c-discount, c-grant,c-paid, c-due) values ('" +textBox5.Text.ToString() + "'," + dateTimePicker1.Text + "," + diccombo.Text.Trim() + "," + GRANTTXT.Text + "," + TXTPAID.Text + ","+ txtdue.Text + ")";
```

Before this, Check whether your autonumber's identity specification sets to true or not ?

Comment: Check with my answer now. Change your syntax with my above line of code